# Jquery Mobile - loading issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, xhtml

I have googled this and can't seem to find the correct resolution, however this maybe my lack of googling skills.

I am currently using the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

which i beleive to be the correct stable release and compatible libraries to use.

everytime i click a link on the mobile website an Ajax like loading icon appears and takes an age to load the link. The website works fine if i take out the 3 above scripts, but at current i am not using the jquery mobile libraries and have put them into the source so i can start to use them. However everything is significantly slower and some pages just stick on the loading ajax loader.

Does anyone know what or why this happens?

Comment: jQM loads pages via Ajax, you can disable it to load pages normally. To test it, add `data-ajax=false` attribute to any `a` anchor.

Comment: rather then adding it to an a anchor. Can you add it inside a $(document).ready to disable it?

Comment: to disable it completely: `$(document).on('mobileinit', function () { $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; });` should be placed in `head` after jquery and before jquery mobile. Note: never use `.ready()` in jqm. Global settings of jqm http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: can you bung this into an answer ans just give a little reason as to why not to use ready on jqm so i can mark as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile loads pages via *Ajax* as it depends on hash URL changes and *Ajax* navigation.

To disable loading pages via *Ajax*, you need to follow any of the methods below.

1) Globally:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('mobileinit', function () { 
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
  });
</script>
<script src="js/jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

2) Specifically:

```
<a href="#" data-ajax="false">Link<a/>
<input type="submit" data-ajax="false" /> <!-- commonly used for submitting data without Ajax -->
```

References:

- [Ajax Navigation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html)
- [Global configations](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html)
- [document.ready vs jQM events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events)